# Ubuntu 10.04.4 32 bit not detecting Acer monitor

Tags: 10.04, monitor

Acer monitor AL2216w 1680x1050 cannot do anything execpt attach different monitor.

This started happening after latest system update. Reloaded Ubuntu back on hard drive still did not help. Took out one of my Nvidia video cards and still nothing. Attached different monitor and it detected that monitor and started working. I could log in and update the system, but switching back to old monitor still doesn't detect.

The monitor shows the bios screen has green light and then after cursor in the upper left cornor goes away the screen turns black and the button color turns to yellow.

Video cards are nvidia 8800gtx. Currently only running 1 card but would like to go back to SLI mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup of your Xorg file then restore it. Sounds like the update overwrote your Xorg configuration.

OR

Boot into your system using recovery console. Pressing SHIFT while in GRUB should give you the option.

Now execute the following commands:

```
user@ubuntu ~# sudo service gdm stop
```

This command will stop the X.

Now we need to generate the xorg.conf file:

```
user@ubuntu ~# sudo Xorg -configure
```

This has generated the file in `~/xorg.conf.new.`

We need to make the X using it so we have to put this file inside `/etc/X11/`

```
user@ubuntu ~# sudo mv ~/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

After moving this file to the proper location you can start the X again and see what happens:

```
user@ubuntu ~# sudo service gdm start
```